# MySQL Stored Procedure fails with ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ddl, database-partitioning

I have written a MySQL stored procedure that will add a new partition to an existing table:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cr_par //

CREATE PROCEDURE cr_par (
    IN p_table VARCHAR(256),
    IN p_date DATE
) BEGIN

    DECLARE stmt      VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE ddl       VARCHAR(512);
    DECLARE par_name  VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE par_no    INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE lt_value  INT DEFAULT 0;
    
    SET par_no   = TO_DAYS(p_date) + 1;
    SET par_name = CONCAT('p', par_no);
    SET lt_value = par_no + 1;
    
    SET ddl = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', p_table, ' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', par_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', lt_value, '))');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SELECT ddl;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I run the stored procedure I get this error:

```
mysql> CALL cr_par('test', '2021-09-13');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

If I comment out the PREPARE, EXECUTE and DEALLOCATE statements and re-run the stored procedure I get this, which is a valid DDL statement:

```
mysql> CALL cr_par('test', '2021-09-13');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ddl                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p738412 VALUES LESS THAN (738413)) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I've also tried these variations and all return the same error:

```
    SET ddl = 'ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p738412 VALUES LESS THAN (738413));';

    PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and this...

```
    SET ddl = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ? ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ? VALUES LESS THAN (?))');
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @p_table, @par_no, @lt_value;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I am using this version of MySQL:

```
Server version: 8.0.25-15 Percona Server (GPL), Release 15, Revision a558ec2
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this, I must be missing something simple?

Comment: Put `SELECT ddl;` before `PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;`. Ensure that the statement to be prepared is the same. Check SP's SQL SECURITY setting. Create complete example code (DDL for existing table) for issue reproducing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'd already checked the GRANTS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET ddl = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', p_table, ' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', par_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', lt_value, '))');

PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;
```

Please be aware that `ddl` and `@ddl` are two different variables.

The variables you declare with the [local variable DECLARE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) have a scope within the body of one stored routine. They are never spelled with a `@` sigil.

The [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) with the `@` sigil have a scope of a MySQL session. You don't need to declare these kinds of variables. Just setting the variable to a value implicitly creates the variable.

You cannot `SET ddl = ...` and expect that string to be read from the `@ddl` variable. Nor vice-versa.

The `PREPARE` statement only supports preparing an SQL from a user-defined variable. Which means you must set the `@ddl` variable to your SQL statement:

```
SET @ddl = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', p_table, ' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION ', par_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', lt_value, '))');
```

Then you don't need to `DECLARE ddl` at all, since there's no use for that variable.

Comment: Thanks @bill, it was indeed the 'SET ddl =' as you mentioned. Once I made that change it worked as expected.